# How to Pass a Javascript Variable to Php and i need change a list color

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is my PHP Code :-

```
echo'<li><input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" onclick="myFunction()" required  value="'.$option_id1.'">'.$option1.'</li>
<br /><br />';
echo'<li><input type="radio" id="option2" name="option2"  onclick="myFunction()" required  value="'.$option_id2.'">'.$option2.'</li>
<br /><br />';
```

This is my JavaScript Code :-

```
function myFunction() {

var var1 = document.getElementById("option1").value;
var var2 = document.getElementById("option2").value;
var var5 = "<?php echo $ans; ?>";

if(var5==var1)
{
    document.getElementById("option1").style.color = "green";
}
else if(var5==var2)
{
    document.getElementById("option1").style.color = "green";   
}
}
```

Comment: The only way to get data from Javascript (client-side) to PHP (server-side) is with a web request. This can be following a link to a new page or an AJAX request.

Comment: @sorak How to ge a data via ajax,can you explain or give me a code for above programs

Comment: What you're trying to do is not clear. I was just responding to the title. Where does `$ans` come from? If `radio1` or `radio2` equals `$ans` you want it to turn green? There's a lot missing from your question.

Answer (score 0):

from your PHP code, i can see you are using `""`

You have to change the `var var5 = "<?php echo $ans; ?>";`

to

`var var5 = '<?php echo $ans; ?>';`

Hope this helps

Comment: It's working fine but what i need mean change a colors in javascript  and pass a varible to my php with color..?

Answer (score 0):

Always use pure JavaScript Code.

PHP Code :-

```
echo'<li><input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" onclick="myFunction()" required  value="'.$option_id1.'">'.$option1.'</li>
<br /><br />';
echo'<li><input type="radio" id="option2" name="option2" onclick="myFunction()" required  value="'.$option_id2.'">'.$option2.'</li>
<br /><br />';

echo'<input type="hidden" id="answer" name="answer" value="'.$ans.'">';
```

JavaScript Code :-

```
function myFunction() {

    var var1 = document.getElementById("option1").value;
    var var2 = document.getElementById("option2").value;
    var var5 = document.getElementById("answer").value;

    if(var5==var1) {
        document.getElementById("option1").style.color = "green";
    }
    else if(var5==var2) {
        document.getElementById("option2").style.color = "green";   
    }
}
```